# Django: international routes

Tags: django, django-urls, django-i18n

My routes are like that:

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^{0}/'.format(_('produits')),
        include('produits.urls', namespace="produits")
        ),
)
```

I thought the `format(_('produits'))` would adapt itself, so I've made two `.po` files:

```
makemessages -l en
makemessages -l fr
```

and in the english `.po` file, i've changed that:

```
#: .\pyweb\urls.py:31
msgid "produits"
msgstr "products"
```

I've then restarted the webserver, and I still have:

- `http://localhost:8000/en/produits/` -> ok
- `http://localhost:8000/en/products/` -> page not found

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you have to wrap the whole argument to the url function like described in [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns)

Comment: I've already read this, I tried everything including `url(_(r'^produits/'), include('produits.urls', namespace="produits"))` but only `/fr/produits/` works

Comment: `_(r'^produits/')` is the correct way. Did you add the complete regex string to your `.po` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.format()`, the lazily translated string is evaluated immediately at import time. You want a single pattern with a lazily translated string as the regex. This means you have to translate the whole regex.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(_(r'^produits/'),
        include('produits.urls', namespace="produits")
        ),
)
```

This way, the regex pattern will change depending on the current language for the request, as the lazy translation is only evaluated when you use `resolve()` or `reverse()`.

You have to add the complete regex to your `.po` files:

```
#: .\pyweb\urls.py:31
msgid "^produits/"
msgstr "^products/"
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, re-compile messages `makemessages -l en` and `makemessages -l fr`, then modified the new `"^produits/"` that appeared then `compilemessages` then restart webserver. Only those two routes are ok `/en/produits/` and `/fr/produits/` which implies `produits` is not properly translated for english. I've tried both ugettext and ugettext_lazy for translation.

Comment: I dont like zvadim solution but it works. It adds ALL the languages of Django in the routes, which is kind of nonsense, but they are all translated. Maybe this can give you a clue to find a "cleaner" solution?

Comment: This is the officially recommended way, as seen in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns). Make sure you use `ugettext_lazy` and restart the server again.

Comment: Already tried all your solution before you bring it here, sorry to say that... I'll try again step by step

Comment: Ok, first things first: make sure you can translate the regex in e.g. a shell.

Comment: Ok I found the problem: in the `.po` english file, everything was the same than french. Everything but the line I was interested in: first line was identical: `#: .\pyweb\urls.py:29` but then gettext has added those two strange lines in the english file: `#, fuzzy` and `#| msgid "produits"`. I've removed them, ran `compilemessages` again and now it seems to work. Strange.

Answer (score -1):

Try think in this way:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import translation
...    
for lng in settings.LANGUAGES:
    lng_code = lng[0]
    with translation.override(lng_code):
        urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
            url(r'^{0}/'.format(_('produits')),
            include('produits.urls', namespace="produits")
            )
        )
```

Comment: This implies reducing LANGUAGES to the ones we use in the settings.